# Setting imageView.image causes unbounded memory growth

Tags: swift, uiimageview

### Steps

1. Create UIImages in array
2. Load UIImage into reusable collection view cell
3. Scroll
4. View memory XCode

[image]

### Code that repros the issue

```
import UIKit

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
  static let ReuseIdentifier = "reuseID"
  var imageView: UIImageView

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    imageView = UIImageView()
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(imageView)
  }
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }
  
  override func layoutSubviews() {
    imageView.frame = bounds
    super.layoutSubviews()
  }
  
  func configureWith(image: UIImage) {
    imageView.image = image
    layoutSubviews()
  }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
  
  var images:[UIImage] = []
  var collectionView: UICollectionView
  
  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    collectionView.register(Cell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: Cell.ReuseIdentifier)
    super.init(coder: coder)
  }
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.frame = view.frame
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .green
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    loadMoreImages()
    collectionView.reloadData()
  }
  
  func loadMoreImages() {
    for _ in 0...50 {
      images.append(cloneImage(image: UIImage(named: "bigImage")!))
    }
  }
  
  // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(images.count)
    return images.count
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Cell.ReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.configureWith(image: images[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }
  
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return view.frame.size
  }
  
}

func cloneImage(image:UIImage) -> UIImage {
  let newCgIm = image.cgImage!.copy()!
  let newImage = UIImage(cgImage: newCgIm, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
  return newImage
}
```

Video demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRDWl.gif

### Things that resolve the issue

- Make UIImages optional, and set UIImages to nil after they've been displayed
- Comment out `imageView.image = image`
- Not using `cloneImage`, and instead `images.append(UIImage(named: "bigImage")!)`

**Any idea what UIImageView is doing under the hood that causes unbounded memory growth?** Seems like it's allocating a bunch of memory in the UIImage object that never gets released.